# Help with grammar number

Tags: grammar, translation, nouns, colors

I have trouble translating the next:

よしおさんの車は赤と白です。

What is the correct translation to the sentence?

1. Yoshio-san's car is red and white
2. Yoshio-san's cars are (one) red and (the other) white

Comment: Japanese is a language that hugely depends on context. Certain translation can mean completely different things by themselves versus being inserted into a sentence or an entire conversation.

Comment: There's no way that there is a car painted red and white...There it is!
http://p.ke-s.cc/images/response/response.jp/imgs/zoom/291156.jpg
That's very cool.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the context and circumstances, it could actually mean EITHER

Just by itself, one could say it means "Yoshio-san's car is red and white"

Answer (score 1):

I think-

**★Yoshio-san's car is red and white.**

is most  correct translation. The second translation,

**★Yoshio-san's cars are (one) red and (the other) white**

just make CARS as plural, but the sense is not changed as Yoshio-san has 2 cars out of which one in red and other is white.

It can mean that "**All the cars Yoshio-san has are red and white**".

Comment: I would highly advice you to avoid adding any suffix to a noun to make it plural when speaking Japanese unless ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY, it is very redundant to native speakers and some will see it as very strange most of the time